# How to set jquery cookie for a URL with Fragment?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using the jquery cookie plug-in https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.

I saw this reference on how to build a URL with Fragment:
[AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html)

The final url rule looks like this:

```
localhost/site/search#!key__searchword&page=1
localhost/site/search#!key__searchword&page=2
localhost/site/search#!key__searchword&page=3
```

(original url should like this: `localhost/site/search?_escaped_fragment_key=searchword&page=1`)

Each above page has one button, I want to check:

- If user never clicked, he/she can do the click,
- If user has clicked, then add class `voted` for forbidden click again.
- I want set cookie for 7 days.

My javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".up").live('click',function() {
    $.cookie('up', 'vote', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'http://127.0.0.1/site/' });
    var up = $.cookie('up');
    if (up == 'vote') {
        $(".up").addClass('voted');
    };
  });
});
```

In anycase, the jquery cookie does not work for me.  How can I set the jquery cookie for a URL with Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the cookie **after** checking whether the cookie exists or not A basic implementation should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".up").live('click',function() {
    var up = $.cookie('upvote');
    var currentLoc = location.hash;
    if (up && up.indexOf(currentLoc) == -1) {
        $(this).addClass('voted');
    };
    else {
        var saveCookie = up ? up + currentLoc : currentLoc;
        $.cookie('upvote', saveCookie, { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'http://127.0.0.1/site/' });
        //rest of functions
    }
  });
});
```

The current location is retrieved through `location.hash`. If the location's hash already exists in the cookie, the `Already voted` routine is followed. Else, a cookie is updated.

Note that this script will prevent a user from voting for seven days, each time the cookie is updated. You can use the hash as a cookie name if you want to set the seven day penalty individually for each page.

Comment: thanks for the answer, still not work. can not make add class event. `alert(currentLoc)`, get `#!key__searchword&page=1`.

Comment: still not worked. I am not really know how to check cookie in jquery? checked the last hash part `page=1` for compare? and I also not know  `path` and `domain` set.

Comment: Please show more efforts in asking questions. What error messages do you get?

Comment: no error messages, in firebug and chrome. just no affection. so how to check if the cookie saved?

Comment: You can get the value of a cookie using `$.cookie("upvote");` (assuming that your cookie is called "upvote"). If the cookie doesn't exist, the function returns `null`.

Comment: `alert(up);` is null, so it should set cookie first, then make `if else` judgement?

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are never sent to the server, so you cannot set a cookie for a fragment.  You can only set a cookie for the path, and it defaults to the path up to the last forward slash I believe according to the RFC.

Comment: in google AJAX Applications Crawlable, this `escaped fragment` can be caught by web search spider. so i think this might be saved with cookies.